# Links not appearing in IE or Opera

Tags: internet-explorer, hover, opera, hyperlink

I have tested my website on Safari and Firefox on both PC and Mac and the links work fine. However, my links show up as just plain text on Internet Explorer and Opera. What am I doing wrong? This is my header where my links are contained. It is on several of my pages. The original website is t h e p i c k l e . t k I spaced inbetween all URLs in my code because this site won't let me more than one hyperlink.

My header source is viewable at http://thepickle.hostzi.com/myheader.php
I tried to post the source directly, but the website wouldn't let me post hyperlinks, even if I spaced between them. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td
      <a href="index.html">home</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="http://thepickle.hostzi.com/phpBB3/index.php">forum</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="apply.html">apply</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="news.html">news</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="faq.html">faq</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="about.html">about</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="contact.html">contact</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="donate.html">donate</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

thats your code.  You need to add the > at the end of your .  Also you have a table close with no table open.  So basically, look over make sure all the nested table code is closed and opened properly.

FIXED:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <a href="index.html">home</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="http://thepickle.hostzi.com/phpBB3/index.php">forum</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="apply.html">apply</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="news.html">news</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="faq.html">faq</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="about.html">about</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="contact.html">contact</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="donate.html">donate</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several bugs with your HTML code, causing it not to render properly.

Mainly, in the section

```
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td
      <a href="index.html">home</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="http://thepickle.hostzi.com/phpBB3/index.php">forum</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="apply.html">apply</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="news.html">news</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="faq.html">faq</a></td>

      <td
      <a href="about.html">about</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="contact.html">contact</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="donate.html">donate</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
```

there needs to be an opening `<table>` tag, and your `<td>` tags are not closed (they're `<td` instead of `<td>`)

Answer (score 0):

In this section:

```
<tbody>

    <tr>
      <td
      <a href="index.html">home</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="http://thepickle.hostzi.com/phpBB3/index.php">forum</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="apply.html">apply</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="news.html">news</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="faq.html">faq</a></td>

      <td
      <a href="about.html">about</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="contact.html">contact</a></td>
      <td
      <a href="donate.html">donate</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Your "`<td`"s are missing closing "`>`"s The correct code should look like:

```
<tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
      <a href="index.html">home</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="http://thepickle.hostzi.com/phpBB3/index.php">forum</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="apply.html">apply</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="news.html">news</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="faq.html">faq</a></td>

      <td>
      <a href="about.html">about</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="contact.html">contact</a></td>
      <td>
      <a href="donate.html">donate</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have no DOCTYPE or Character Encoding specified, so any browser is currently just guessing what you're intending to do. Your links are all held within a table (missing its starting tag), but tables are not supported in all document types and perhaps Firefox and Safari are guessing better.

I suggest you read this :

[W3C Validator Result](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fthepickle.hostzi.com%2Fmyheader.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)